# Lava lamp menu - how to change text color inside hover box

Tags: javascript, lavalamp

I have implemented Lava Lamp menu using jQuery. I would like to know if it is possible to change color of text inside hover box.
For e.g.
Below is the default lamp menu where hover box is on "Home" and font color of text inside hover box is red whereas all other text color is black

[image: Default lava lamp menu]

Below is the image in which hover box is moving on "Community". Notice the text color inside hover box is being changed to red and all other text color is black.

[image: Lava lamp menu when hovered on Community - hover box is moving]

Below is html snippet :

```
<ul class="lavalamp">
       <li class="default-item"><span>Home</span></li>
       <li><span>Community</span></li>
       <li><span>FAQ</span></li>
       <li><span>Contact Us</span></li>
       <li class="hover-box"></li> 
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should put it up on JSfiddle

Comment: Easiest would be to put a transparent png in the hover box with certain color filters and transparencies set, but I don't think that is the solution for what your asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look **[Here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/)**, or the actual **[Article](http://css-tricks.com/5582-jquery-magicline-navigation/)**. The second example in conjunction with `background-origin` should do the trick I believe.

Comment: I referred that 2 days a go but its still not spilling solution for my problem :(